# Select info from mysql-database and show on page

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to show some info from a mysql database on a page, but I get an error. Used code:

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET["id"]));
$newsarticle = ($_GET["id"]);
$dbhost = 'localhost';
$dbuser = 'root';
$dbpass = '';
$dbname = 'XXXX';
$conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass) or die ('Error      connecting to mysql');
mysql_select_db($dbname);
$searchroute ="SELECT NewsText FROM News WHERE id=$newsarticle";
$handle = mysql_query($searchroute);
$NewsText = mysql_fetch_row($handle);
?>
```

And later in my code:

```
<?php echo "$NewsText" ?>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This is the 'error':

Notice: Array to string conversion in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/single.php on line 124
Array

Comment: First: **Stop** using deprecated `mysql_*` API. Use `mysqli_*` or `PDO`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mysql_fetch_row()` will return array so in your case it should be, `echo $NewsText[0];`

If you use `mysql_fetch_array()` then you can use `echo $NewsText['NewsText'];`

Comment: Then I get this: Notice: Undefined index: NewsText in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/single.php on line 124

Answer (score 0):

**1)** Change

`if (isset($_GET["id"]));`

To

`if (isset($_GET["id"])){`

And, Add `}` below `$NewsText = mysql_fetch_row($handle);` to close `if`

**2)** Change

```
$newsarticle = ($_GET["id"]);
```

To

```
$newsarticle = $_GET["id"];
```

**3)** Put `$NewsText = mysql_fetch_row($handle);` in while loop

```
while($NewsText = mysql_fetch_row($handle)){
  echo $NewsText[0]."<br>";
}
```

**Updated Code:**

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET["id"])){
  $newsarticle = $_GET["id"];
  $dbhost = 'localhost';
  $dbuser = 'root';
  $dbpass = '';
  $dbname = 'XXXX';
  $conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass) or die ('Error      connecting to mysql');
  mysql_select_db($dbname);
  $searchroute ="SELECT NewsText FROM News WHERE id=$newsarticle";
  $handle = mysql_query($searchroute);
  while($NewsText = mysql_fetch_row($handle)){
    echo $NewsText[0]."<br>";
  }
}
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to iterate over the result set.

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result))
{
    echo $row['NewsText'];
}
```

If you know there will be one record you can do it like:

```
echo $row[0]['NewsText'];
```

make sure you perform index check using `key_exists` to avoid exceptions.

Note: Stop using deprecated `mysql_*` API. Use `mysqli_*` or `PDO`

Comment: Thank you for the help, but then it doesn't show anything. In my database I have something so that is not the problem.

Comment: echo $searchroute and execute the query in mysql and see if you get resutls or not

Answer (score -1):

Use

```
$row = mysql_fetch_row($result);
```

and then

`<?php echo $row["NewsText"]; ?>`

Comment: I get this: Notice: Undefined variable: result in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/single.php on line 124

Warning: mysql_fetch_row() expects parameter 1 to be resource, null given in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/single.php on line 124

Comment: And if I change your $result into my $handle it doesn't show anything.